# how to see history of a normal user from root

Tags: bash, root, history

If I am logged in as `root`, how will I be able to see history of other users.
I tried using `su -c` but it's blank for history command 
for example if I run the following command from root

```
root@server:#su -c 'who am i' user1

user1 pts/0        2019-08-12 10:30

root@server:#su -c 'history' user1
```

this command doesn't return anything.

I want to see timestamps on user history which is not possible by just looking at `/home/user1/.bash_history` and that is why I want to use history command to get the output with timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and inputs everyone!! I am still trying to figure out why history command run for a user from root shell doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where bash stores command history by default is in `.bash_history`, and it doesn't store timestamps in that file. When history is loaded from a history file, it's all loaded with the timestamp that the shell started.

I'm not immediately sure why running `history` from `su` doesn't work, but it's a moot point. You wouldn't see anything that you couldn't get by viewing the user's history file directly.

Comment: I tried running history command for the user from root shell but for some reason the response is empty. The bash_history file is definitely there to look at, but I am trying to log history with timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see timestamps on user history which is not possible by just looking at `/home/user1/.bash_history`

Timestamps may or may not be in this file. Nowhere else (unless the user deliberately used *another* file instead; I assume you identified the right file). From `man 1 bash`:

> `HISTTIMEFORMAT`
>   If this variable is set and not null, its value is used as a format string for `strftime(3)` to print the time stamp associated with each history entry displayed by the `history` builtin. If this variable is set, time stamps are written to the history file so they may be preserved across shell sessions. This uses the history comment character to distinguish timestamps from other history lines.

If `user1` had the variable set and not null (e.g. `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T: "`), entries in `/home/user1/.bash_history` would look like this:

```
#1568346641
ls -hls /
```

where the number `1568346641` is "seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`" (like in `date +%s`, see `man 1 date`). These are timestamps you seek. If there are no such entries in the file then it's too late: timestamp information has not been saved, it's gone.

---

In practice you may want to run this:

```
# as root
cp /home/user1/.bash_history /root/user1_history
chmod -w /root/user1_history
HISTFILE="/root/user1_history"
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T: "
history -c
history -r
 history | less
```

(The last command begins with space so it's not stored in the current history you're about to see).

If there are timestamps in the file then you will see them in a human-readable form (according to `HISTTIMEFORMAT` we used). Missing timestamps will be substituted with the time your current shell started at and there's nothing you can do.

---

Note `/home/user1/.bash_history` is not a very reliable way to see what the user did. The user may have:

- used another shell,
- used another file,
- chosen not to save the file,
- made the shell not remember certain commands,
- planted a "counterfeit" file.

Depending on what you want to find, maybe you will be lucky with `/var/log/auth.log` (Debian and like) or `/var/log/secure` (some other distros, I believe). In my Debian I can see in logs who (and when) did `sudo vipw` or `sudo bash`, but I cannot see commands they invoked in a shell spawned by `sudo bash`. There are solutions that may help (e.g. `auditd`) but you need to set them up beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

`history` is a bash built-in, that can retrieve:

- commands issued in this very bash session (so for recent commands it has to be run from the shell process that issued the commands).
- commands issued in previous, *terminated* sessions, using the `~/.bash_history` file. This assumes that these commands have been saved in the history (but this can be disabled by un-setting the HISTFILE variable(*)). Furthermore, as far as I know the history of the current session is appended to the history file only *when the shell exits*.

In other words looking at the history file only gives you commands issued in a somewhat distant past, and you cannot see the commands issued in a currently running session.

(*) In practice there is not much penalty in doing this, most command retrievals are for commands issued in the current session.